# Split a string to extract double value out of it

Tags: java, string

How can I convert `String s="3.78 hi bye"` to `double c=3.78`?

Same question for `String s="hi 3.78 hi bye"` (take only 3.78 while ignoring the text before)

Comment: Do you mean precisely 3.78 or any decimal number?

Comment: What didn't you found on Google??

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: +1 for Andrew's comment. A simple look into the javadoc should solve this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex to get rid of all characters that are not a digit or a `.`:

```
String s = "hi 3.78 hi bye";
String numberOnly = s.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]+", "");
double d = Double.parseDouble(numberOnly); //d == 3.78d
```

You should add some exception handling in case the original string is not properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

you may try to use regular expression

```
Pattern doubleValue = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
Matcher m = doubleValue.match(yourString);
if (m.find()) {
   return Double.parseDouble(m.group(0));
}
return null;
```

Comment: Pattern must be: `[+-]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][+-]?\d+)?`